# Make my UIViewController fullscreen in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an Objective C project which uses XIB files (not storyboards).

I have a UIViewController view that I lunch from my AppDelegate.m file which plays a video.  I want to make it full screen but the title
bar at the top is showing and there is a thin white line down the left hand side of the screen.

How can I make the whole video play full screen.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    VideoIntroViewController *videoIntroViewController = [[VideoIntroViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VideoIntroViewController" bundle:nil];
    videoIntroViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:videoIntroViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return YES;
}
```

**VideoIntroViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{   
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (!self.navigationController.toolbarHidden)
    {
        [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self createVideoPlayer];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)createVideoPlayer
{
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"welcome_video" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    self.player.volume = PLAYER_VOLUME;

    AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
    playerLayer.videoGravity = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill; <-- 'Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument'
    playerLayer.frame = self.playerView.layer.bounds;
    [self.playerView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];

    [self.player play];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayDidEnd:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:self.player.currentItem];
}
```

Comment: Do not add your root view controller's view as a subview of the window. Set the window's `rootViewController` property instead. And if you don't want the navbar why use a navigation controller?

Answer (score 2):

Hide navigation bar in AppDelegate itself:

```
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:videoIntroViewController];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Set navigation bar hidden:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following line,

```
[self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
```

You have already set rootViewController of self.window.

If you ever need to add subview (here you do not need) and you are using autoLayout on that view controller/view, you have to add constraint in storyboard/xib file or by writing code for that view.